# Execution order firebase auth

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to login with firebase authentication with facebook sdk and "user/password" options in android. I need to know what kind of authentication the user has used before start MainActivity.

Days ago the code used to work fine, but I had to erase the firebase project. Today I configured the firebase/facebook sdk and it works. But now the order of execution of the code is different (I know is very weird).

Before, `onComplete` method (when I validate if the task is successful) is executed first and then `onAuthStateChanged`. But now first `onAuthStateChanged` method is executed first, start the other activity and then validate if the task is successful. I see that behavior in debug mode.

here is the code example and I am grateful in advance for any help

```
fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            //Inicio de sesion con facebook exitoso
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //Inicio de sesion con facebook cancelado
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.cancel_fb_log,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            //Inicio de sesion con facebook erroneo
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.error_fb_log,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
    //Iniciar sesión con una credencial
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        //metodo que se ejecuta al terminar el proceso
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                //Ocurrio un error al realizar el logueo a firebase con facebook
                Utilities.exceptionFirebaseAdministrator(LoginActivity.this, task, LOG_TAG);
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            }else{
                pref.edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_logged_with_facebook),true).apply();
                pref.edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_logged_with_firebase),false).apply();
            }
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

fireAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if(user != null){

//I try use SharedPreference and validate if is facebook login or other
                    startMainActivity();

            }

        }
    };

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //Cuando la clase empieza a "escuchar"
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(fireAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //Cuando la clase deja de "escuchar"
    firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(fireAuthStateListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this changes in your code ,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // this is the login layout change it to yours.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // START initialize_auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // START auth_state_listener
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
              //check if user is  not null 
            if (user != null) {

// below code will triggers as soon as your facebook login task is successful                   


      // this will return provider as facebook,google,twitter,email ,etc

                String provider = user.getProviders().get(0) ;

                  pref.edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_logged_with_facebook), true).apply();
                  pref.edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_logged_with_firebase), false).apply();
  //I try use SharedPreference and validate if is facebook login or other
                startMainActivity();


            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "user signed_out");
                // logout user and open login page .
            }
        }
    };


}

// [START on_start_add_listener]
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

// [START on_stop_remove_listener]
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}


private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
    //Iniciar sesión con una credencial
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        //metodo que se ejecuta al terminar el proceso
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                // If sign in fails, log message or go back to login page.         
                //If sign in succeeds the auth state listener will be  
               //notified and logic to handle the
              // signed in user can be handled in the listener.

                Utilities.exceptionFirebaseAdministrator(LoginActivity.this, task, LOG_TAG);
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            }
              // this will execute no matter whats happens ,
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: that is other form and it works thanks (how can i vote feedback i only click the up arrow for now) but it seems very weird that some times the order of execution is onComplete and later onAuthStateChanged.

Is there any way to know in onAuthStateChanged method if the user is register using facebook or email/password steps?

Comment: yes you can check provider using  user.getProviders().get(0) ,return type is  string , use this in if(user!=null) . see the edited answer above

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseAuth does a tricky job, when you starts app firebase AuthStateListener executes  first to look for any status changed i.e if user is logged in or logged out.
In your code you add AuthStateListener  in on start thats why every time your app starts it override  other methods and executes  AuthStateListener first. 
 It is always a good practice  to add AuthStateListener in on start and remove it on on stop method Which is also recommended by firebase  engineer . 
You are doing it right ,in application  which requires user authentication  always check user status and then perform any task realted to them .

```
     Override
    public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
//Cuando la clase empieza a "escuchar"
firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(fireAuthStateListener);
```

}

Comment: But block code in onComplete method is executed when authstate finished but shouldn't onConplete code execute and when it finished trigger authstatechanged?

Comment: do this  write  firebaseAuthsatateListner method in onCreate method of your activity. every time your activity opens firebasauthstatListner will check for status of user.  when user tries to login using facebook then if task is successful  the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
signed in user can be handled in the listener.

Comment: the flow of execution goes like this ...  firebase authStateListener (this time status user is null)- your facebook login oncomplete method(if task is successful) - then again firebsaeauthstateListner.(this time status chnges to user!=null)

Comment: it is that the problem when i'm in debug mode i see that signInWithCredential launch first then firebssaeauthstateListner execute and last block code inside onComplete method,  when validate if the user use facebook login always return false because the code that evaluate that that excecute after

Comment: did you wirte FirebaseAuthStateListner in onCreate() ?

Comment: see this example from firebase  it uses google login  , notice oncreate () in this code ..Firebaseauthstatelistner is implimented in oncreate.. hope this will help you .https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java

Comment: i gonna take a look the example and yes i have the method on onCreate()  indeed i try have the login option in one activity and in a fragment in onCreateView() but both have the same behavior

Comment: first thanks a lot Sagar but i see the example but is very similar in my code, but the problem keep, onComplete method is executed later and first the onAuthStateChanged

Comment: your problem is that the last piece of code from onClomplet() is executed later right?  this happens because .. as soon as the onComplete method starts if task is successful then firebaseAuth triggers first and chnges its status to user!=null ,and then this piece of remaining code starts executing after that.  what you can do is that remove this piece of code from onComplete and paste it in  if(user!=null) .

Comment: i did some changes in your code check if this will help you  see below new answer . comment if any problem occurs